# Why do I always have a blank line at the bottom of a console application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application which I'm trying to treat like a terminal. Even terminals don't go this far to make sure the format is perfect, but I have OCD with this kind of thing, and wish to do it.

Once I've typed about 10 or 20 lines into the terminal, I reach a place where my input cursor is right at the bottom of the console window, and there isn't a blank line underneath.

I just think things would go much better if there was a line below at all lines. So after my while loop, I've attempted this, but it doesn't seem to help with the problem I'm currently facing.

```
private static void PrintLineToBottom()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

Can anyone help here? I suppose it also needs to know when it needs to do this.

Comment: What you are looking for is a feature called "Console Virtual Terminal Sequences".  Current docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences.  You get to control the appearance of the console window by sending "control sequences" to the window.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what you’re trying to do, but if you feel like this is additional “gold plating” then I guess I’d worry about some more important thing. UX with console is already as bad as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem with your method is that it doesn't write anything to the console window. If you add an argument and write it to the console, it should work as expected.

This example uses an `object` with a default value of `null`, but you could create many overloads to mimic the actual `WriteLine` method. It's basically the same code that you have, except that it prints the argument to the window plus a newline character, then moves the cursor up one space. I also added an optional argument to change the number of blank lines below the last line:

```
private static void TerminalWriteLine(object output = null, int numBlankLinesBelow = 1)
{
    // Don't allow negative numbers
    numBlankLinesBelow = Math.Max(0, numBlankLinesBelow);
    Console.WriteLine(output + new string('\n', numBlankLinesBelow));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop - numBlankLinesBelow);
}
```

Then you would use this method in your code in place of `Console.WriteLine`, for example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        TerminalWriteLine(i);                
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
    TerminalWriteLine("There should be 5 blank lines below this", 5);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output after first `ReadLine()`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Output after second `ReadLine()`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: This works well, the only problem with it is if you scroll up, and then scroll back down to the bottom, it doesn't stop where you last left off, it scrolls much further down for a while. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that you can scroll down further than the blank line below the output? If so, that's due to the buffer size settings on your console window. If you set the buffer size to the same size as the window, it will prevent scrolling: `Console.SetBufferSize(Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

**Hello there!**

I had to sign up just to give *your question* a real and correct answer.

WriteLine() with no params, is 100% okay, and it doesn't cause issues. I'm sorry about *Rufus L*.

- Your function shouldn't be called after the loop. It won't be called then until you break loop.
- That's all I can say without more code giving context to your words.

It's always nice to*recreate your code as excerpts if you wish to keep your code private, like below.

---

The correct answer is the simplest. Copy and paste this, then play with it.

```
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">");
            Console.CursorTop--;
            Console.CursorLeft++;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

---

At this point, it is answered.

But let's break it all down and have some fun!

---

Print a prompt string (">"), or nothing (), and go to next line as desired.

```
Console.WriteLine(">"); // Or...
Console.WriteLine(); // Blank prompt.
```

---

There are times when it is impossible to know the target position.

```
Console.CursorTop--; // Cursor up by 1.
Console.CursorLeft++; // Right by length of prompt, if not blank.
```

---

The '_' represents the cursor position as is.

```
>_ // Prompt awaiting user input.
```

---

At which point user input can be captured.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Blurb.

I am weird because I love Command Prompt console apps the most. I have made several over the past few years, and only this month created my latest version, the *omg* simplest of the lot, and the absolute best functional--works 100% as Cmd.exe, yet now has **front end** ability to add custom commands, so by default it is Cmd.exe.

My most complex version, the previous version, had amazing custom functionality, including a Terminal function to become a literal terminal. The terminal also had the 'exit' command which snapped you back to my Control Console.

This is literally one of my greatest programming passions. As such, a page full of horrible non-answers are sighted swiftly and with lament.

Hence...

---

In my consoles, I always use the Write function as I haven't desired a sure blank line below.

Write also gives you more control. **Let's get dynamic!**

```
        while (true)
        {
            string prompt = "Terminal> ";
            Console.Write(prompt);
            int count = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) Console.WriteLine();
            Console.CursorTop -= count;
            Console.CursorLeft += prompt.Length;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

---

Now we want the prompt string to be a variable.

```
string prompt = "Terminal> "; // Notice the space.
Console.Write(prompt);
```

---

Here we can decide how many blank lines we want, which can also be decided externally.

```
int count = 5; // Or variable.
```

---

A simple for loop to give us the desired number of blank lines after each prompt.

This is why we do not prompt with WriteLine, as that would give us an extra one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) Console.WriteLine();
```

---

Move the cursor up and right based on the sizes known to us.

```
Console.CursorTop -= count; // Blank lines we printed.
Console.CursorLeft += prompt.Length; // The string length of the prompt.
```

---

The '_' represents the cursor position as is.

```
Terminal> _ // Prompt awaiting user input.
```

---

At which point user input can be captured.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Here is what my code might look like. Copy and paste this function, and have fun!

```
    static void CommandPrompt()
    {
        string input = "";
        string promptString = "Terminal> ";
        int blankLinesCount = 1;

        while (true) PromptLoop();

        // Local functions are a thing.

        string PromptSimple()
        {
            Console.Write(">");
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        string Prompt()
        {
            Console.Write(promptString);
            for (int i = 0; i < blankLinesCount; i++) Console.WriteLine();
            Console.CursorTop -= blankLinesCount;
            Console.CursorLeft += promptString.Length;
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void PromptLoop()
        {
            input = Prompt();

            // Process the input.
        }
    }
```

---

***Enjoy! ♥***